# Line integral and contour integral of a vector field

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, vector-analysis

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral) contour integrals are just line integrals in the complex plane.

So, if we'll recognize $\mathbb{C} $ as $\mathbb{R}^2 $, and if we'll let $\gamma$ be some curve in the complex plane (or in $\mathbb{R}^2$), and a function $ f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C},f=u+iv $ (or as we recognize it $ f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to\mathbb{R}^{2},f\left(x,y\right)=\begin{pmatrix}u\left(x,y\right)\\
v\left(x,y\right)
\end{pmatrix} $)

assume $ \gamma\left(t\right)=\left(x\left(t\right),y\left(t\right)\right),\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace a\leq t\leq b $ or $ \gamma\left(t\right)=x\left(t\right)+iv\left(t\right),\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace a\leq t\leq b $

Im expecting to get the same result for

$ \intop_{\gamma}f\left(z\right)dz=\intop_{a}^{b}f\left(\gamma\left(t\right)\right)\gamma'\left(t\right)dt $

and $ \intop_{\gamma}f\left(r\right)\cdot dr=\intop_{a}^{b}\begin{pmatrix}u\left(x\left(t\right),y\left(t\right)\right)\\
v\left(x\left(t\right),y\left(t\right)\right)
\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}x'\left(t\right)\\
y'\left(t\right)
\end{pmatrix}dt $

But ofcourse that this is not correct (otherwise all the line integrals of functions in $\mathbb{C} $ would be real).

So what exactly do I get wrong in the definitions of the contour\line integrals?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest issue is that the dot product does not and cannot work in the same way on $\mathbb{C}$ as it does on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

The way the dot product you have set up implies that

$$f\left(\gamma\left(t\right)\right)\gamma'\left(t\right) = (u(\gamma)+iv(\gamma))*(x'+iy') = ux'-vy'+i(vx'+uy')$$

Is equal to:

$$u(\gamma)x'+ v(\gamma)y'$$

It should be clear that these aren't the same. In some sense, you're assuming the geometry of the dot product on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the product of two complex numbers are the same, which they are not. If they were:

$$\begin{pmatrix}0\\
1
\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}0\\
1
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-1\\
0
\end{pmatrix} $$

By analogy with $i^2 = -1$. It should not be difficult to see that this last equation is incorrect.

Comment: So when Im calculating the line integral of $ f $ as a real function, I need to use the definition of multipication of complex numbers on the vectors? i.e $ \left(x,y\right)\cdot\left(z,w\right)=\left(xz-yw,xw+yz\right) $ ? (In this case how are we going to integrate over a vector?)

Comment: Or what you're suggesting is that contour integrals in the complex plane and line integrals over vector field function from $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2 $ are different types of integrals and one cannot find the relation between them?

Comment: @FreeZe Contour integrals are integrals of a vector field $g = (f, if) \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{C}^2$, so they have values in $\mathbb{C}$. If you want, you can think of it as a vector field $g \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to (\mathbb{R}^2)^2$. In that case you have a $\mathbb{R}^2$ valued integral. Either way, the contour integral outputs a pair of real numbers, not just one real number, so it is a different object than a line integral.